# Tkinter button disable not working in a another file

Tags: python, tkinter

My python project consists of 2 files the gui part and the actual logic part

In gui.py i have (as the name states) written the code for a tkinter gui like

```py
import logic #the other file required for the working of the program
from tkinter import * #i know this method isnt recommeded but in the near future ill probably put only the submodules i actually require
#gui code(there are a bunch of widgets but 2 main widets are an entry and a button defined like shown below

global but
but=Button(window,text='Click me',fg='#3d3d3d',bg='white',font = ("Arial",14),command=lambda:but_func()))
but.place(relx=0.7,rely=0.93,anchor=CENTER)

global entry
entry=Entry(window,bg='#3d3d3d',fg='white')
entry.place(relx=0.64,rely=0.14,width=370,height=20,anchor=CENTER)

def but_func():
    global but
    global entry
    entry_text=entry.get()
    logic.some_func(button=but,text=entry_text)
```

And in logic.py

```py
def some_func(button,text):
    #if text meets a certain condition
        button['state']='disabled'
        #code
        button['state']='normal'
    else:
        pass
```

And when i click the button with the text that meets the certain condition in the entry the code executes just fine but the button doesnt get disabled. Please help

Comment: i have also tried by importing tkinter constants and using button.config(state=DISABLED) which also didnt work

Comment: Tkinter mainloop takes back the control and update button state *after `some_func()` is executed*.  So you can only see the last state.  You can call `button.update_idletasks()` after `button['state'] = 'disabled'` to force the update.

Comment: Thank you  @acw166 i fashioned a fix from what you said which worked vey well thank you very mch

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from logic import but
```

You import the variable: but from logic, since Tkinter GUI widgets are technically variables, you have to import but.
if that doesn't work, try:

```
from logic import *
```

This will just import everything needed to run.